# Decrypt RSA with known public key and modulus and the range of dp

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

How to decrypt RSA while given $e$,$n$ and the range of $dp$ ?

```
e=2953544268002866703872076551930953722572317122777861299293407053391808199220655289235983088986372630141821049118015752017412642148934113723174855236142887
n=6006128121276172470274143101473619963750725942458450119252491144009018469845917986523007748831362674341219814935241703026024431390531323127620970750816983
```

while $dp$ is in the range of $(1,2^{20})$

Comment: That seems small enough to factor, what have you tried? Note that homework / assignments are off topic, but we may give hints in comments if enough effort has been shown/

Comment: I traversaled the range of dp and tried to calculate p with i in range(1,e) then p=((dp*e-1)/i)+1 but the public exponent is too large to traversale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $d_p$ is the quantity $d \bmod (p-1) = e^{-1} \bmod (p-1)$, from which we get the core property
$$
e\cdot d_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p-1}\,.
$$
For a small $d_p$ we can easily, by bruteforce, find the quantity $e\cdot d_p -1 = k\cdot (p-1)$ for some large unknown integer $k$.

Here we can take a hint from the Pollard $p-1$ factorization method—we have $2^{k(p-1)} = 1 \pmod{p}$, and thus $\gcd(n, 2^{e\cdot d_p - 1} - 1 \bmod n)$ will be $p$ for the right $d_p$.

In your example $d_p = 915155$.